# VS 2013 Database Project - Populating Standing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, merge

I have a couple of merge scripts that are run post deployment, one of which sets up a lookup table as per:

```
MERGE INTO [Languages] AS Target
USING (VALUES
   ('English','eng','en')
  ,('French','fra','fr')
) AS Source ([LanguageName],[Iso639Code],[Locale])
ON (Target.[Iso639Code] = Source.[Iso639Code])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET 
  [LanguageName] = Source.[LanguageName], 
  [Locale] = Source.[Locale],
  [UserModified] = @UpdatedBy,
  [ModifiedDateTime] = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
 INSERT([LanguageName],[Iso639Code],[Locale],[UserCreate],[CreateDateTime])
 VALUES(Source.[LanguageName],Source.[Iso639Code],Source.[Locale],@UpdatedBy,GETDATE());
GO
```

This table has an [int] as the primary key. This script works well.

So my question is I now have another script which needs to look up the primary key from this table to insert into a second table.

```
MERGE INTO [Countries] AS Target
USING (VALUES
   ('England')
  ,('France')
) AS Source ([CountryName])
ON (Target.[CountryName] = Source.[CountryName])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET 
  [CountryName] = Source.[CountryName], 
  [LanguageId] = (Select LanguageID from [Languages] where [LanguageName] = Source.[LanguageName]),
  [Locale] = Source.[Locale],
  [UserModified] = @UpdatedBy,
  [ModifiedDateTime] = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
 INSERT([CountryName],LanguageId,[UserCreate],[CreateDateTime])
 VALUES(Source.[CountryName],(Select LanguageID from [Languages] where [LanguageName] = Source.[LanguageName]),@UpdatedBy,GETDATE());
GO
```

Is this the correct procedure to link the two tables with the post deployment scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around and yes, what I have shown, is exactly how to do what I require.